# codeigniter 3 controller index in url ( no index.php )

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing, codeigniter-3

I've been trying to remove the index from my urls but with no luck when I say index I mean www.mywebsite.com/en/controller/index  not www.mywebsite.com/index.php

I am using codeigniter 3, I am on ubuntu 16.04 so no httpd.conf but mywebsite.com.conf
the mod rewrite is activated, I have another project with codeigniter 2 which is working perfectly.

here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am using a multilanguage website thanks to this plugin
http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n

In my routing I have

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'App';
$route['404_override'] = 'site_404';

$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;    

if ($this->config->item('multilanguage')):          
    $route['^(en|fr)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
    $route['^(en|fr)$'] = "$2";         
endif;
```

and in my controller I have this

```
class App extends MX_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
    }

    public function index()
    {
      /*I load my view here*/
    }
}
```

and I intend to use multiple controllers and multiples methods as well
I have been looking for a solution, but I always find the one about the index.php, not the actual method in the controller ( which stays in the url )

Comment: `$route['^(en|fr)$'] = "$2";` won't this fail?

Comment: And also lower case here `$route['default_controller'] = 'module/app/index';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this as first rule after `RewriteEngine On` (also would be good to set `RewriteBase` with appropriate location):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Tpojka, 

With your htaccess code, there are no more index in the url, but now I have a Not found page.

I am guessing now I need to change few stuffs in my routing, 
I tried 
$route['default_controller'] = 'App'; $route['default_controller'] = 'App/index'; $route['default_controller'] = 'app'; lowercase uppercase etc... no luck either

Comment: In relation to server, is your website root location `/` or `/some_project_directory/`?

Comment: It was in a sub directory, I tried to change the RewriteBase without success, so I ditched the principal website, and plugged the subdirectory to the upper level, I changed with all the advice given here, and it works now. 
I didn't have time to fully check the other routes, but so far everything is ok.
Thank you a lot

Comment: You did half of job I suppose. `RewriteBase /subdir/` and `RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ /subdir/ [L,R=301]`. Of course if so, you have to take care of `$config['base_url']` to end with `/subdir/` too. #SOreadytohelp

Comment: Thank you for all the tips, that must have been it : P

Comment: I have a little issue, in  my previous project I was putting my css js inside application/views, but I know it's not really a good practice, so I would like to move a folder I have inc which contains everything
inc/img
inc/css
inc/js
etc ...

but because I using a multilingual codeigniter, the minify plugin I am using is looking for the css and js at this location

mywebsite.com/en/inc/img ...

instead of mywebsite.com/inc/img ...

How can I change this ?

Comment: in fact I would need a htaccess rule as follow

if( file == css js jpg png etc... )
remove /en/ in url
remove /fr/ in url